# R: Determine if S3 method has a function for a specified class

Tags: r, oop, methods, r-package

I want to write a function that returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending if an S3 method supports a specific class.  For example, if I have a data frame with class `"data.frame"` and the transpose function, `t()`, I want to know if there is a method for class `"data.frame"`.

```r
> my_checking_function(class = "data.frame", function = t)
TRUE
```

The tricky part is that I want to do this for a method that is not attached.  Specifically, I want test if there is a {broom} package tidier (aka  a `tidy()` method) for a model type.  This function will be in a package, which is why I cannot attach {broom} before making the check. Perhaps, something like this, where the {broom} package is not attached:

```r
> my_checking_function(class = "lm", function = broom::tidy)
TRUE
> my_checking_function(class = "not_a_supported_class", function = broom::tidy)
FALSE
```

I found some functions that may work, but I can't get them to work without first attaching the {broom} package.
`utils::.S3methods()`
`sloop::s3_methods_class()`

In the `utils::.S3methods()` you can specify an environment to search.  But I could not figure out a way specify an environment that was the namespace of the {broom} package.

Any tips are much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I am a little confused as to why you can't load `broom`

Comment: `??` could be a friend. Not exact, but `x = ??broom::tidy.lm` and `y = ??broom::tidy.foo`, then testing `nrow(x$matches) > 0` (TRUE) and `nrow(y$matches) > 0` (FALSE). Though I'm sure someone will come up with a more direct way...

Comment: A bit better, `x = help("tidy.lm", package = "broom")`, then `length(x)`. Will only search the `broom` package, if installed. It does rely on the broom package having a help page for the method---which it tends to do.